# Move complete column from one Data Table to other C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datatable, dynamic-columns

I need to implement column shifting functionality between two data tables. Let say i have  columns {A,B,C} in DataTable 1 and {A} in DataTable 2.

If i want to move columns {B,C} to DataTable 2, how can i do this ? The data in both tables should similar.

If DataTable is not a right option , then please help me on how we can achieve this ..

Can this be done with List> - Nested Lists ? Tried below code , but thought merge isn't the right option.

```
  private void move(DataTable source, DataTable dest, string colname)
    {
        var result = source.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>(colname));
        dest.Columns.Add(colname);
        DataTable dt = source.DefaultView.ToTable(false, colname);

        dest.Merge(dt);          

    }
```

I'm beginner , so please suggest if there is any other way where we can shift columns based on the user selection.

Comment: This looks like a *no-so-complex* complex job of duplicating columns, and copying data. What have you tried? Where did you get stucked?

Comment: I tried the below

void ShiftColumn(DataTable source, DataTable dest, string colname)
{
   var result = source.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>  row.Field<string>(colname));

    dest.Columns.Add(colname);
    DataTable dt = source.DefaultView.ToTable(false, colname);
    pd.Merge(dt);
}



}

Comment: I tried to get column name selected by user , and used linq query to get the data with respect to that column and then merged with destination table. Guess merge is not the right option here.


void ShiftColumn(DataTable source, DataTable dest, string colname)
{
   var result = source.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>  row.Field<string>(colname));
    dest.Columns.Add(colname);

    DataTable dt = source.DefaultView.ToTable(false, colname);
    dest.Merge(dt);
}
}

I'm beginner , so please suggest anything else.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add more information. Code is very hard to read in comments

Comment: modified the question, thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime back I had done this. I had to manually write the code for data table copy. The method below does the job of copying missing columns from the source table to the target table. It returns the collection of column names that got copied.
The second function copies the data from source column to the target column. It takes the primary key column name as input and list of column names for which data has to be copied.

```
public List<string> CopyDistinctColumns(DataTable source, DataTable target)
{
    var copiedColumn = new List<string>();
    for(var x = 0; x < source.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        var column = source.Columns[x];
        if(!target.Columns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
        {
            var newCol = new DataColumn
            {
                ColumnName = column.ColumnName,
                DataType = column.DataType,
                Caption = column.Caption,
                DefaultValue = column.DefaultValue,
                MaxLength = column.MaxLength,
            };
            copiedColumn.Add(column.ColumnName);
            target.Columns.Add(newCol);
        }
    }
    return copiedColumn;
}

public void CopyData(DataTable source, DataTable target, string primaryKeyColumnName, List<string> copiedColumns)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = source.Rows[i];
        var primaryKeyValue = row[primaryKeyColumnName];
        for (var j = 0; j < target.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            var trow = target.Rows[j];
            if (trow[primaryKeyColumnName].Equals(primaryKeyValue))
            {
                foreach (var col in copiedColumns)
                {
                    trow[col] = row[col];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ; i got many clues from the code. This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

check there is copy option for data table, 
like
DataTable dt = new DataTable()
dt.copy
or
dt.clone

Comment: Tried them ; but can we copy only specific columns ? My requirement is that user can shift ,  or can we grab the columns and column data into a List and create a nested list of columns and then bind to grid ? will that be good ?

Comment: Datacolumn dc = dt.column[3]; now add like dt2.columns.add(dc)

Comment: if above way does not work, you can easily delete unwanted columns. dt.columns.Romve("columnname")

Comment: we can simply do some thing like   DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            table1.Columns.Add("A");
            table1.Columns.Add("B");
            table1.Columns.Add("C");

            DataTable table2 = table1.Clone();
            table2.Columns.Remove("A");

Comment: @Ravuthasamy, The same i suggested in my previous comment

Comment: var vtable = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3");  now you can use vtale as yuo like